# gedit reverting settings to default

Tags: fedora, xubuntu, gedit

I'd like to revert to the fresh gedit on my system. Any idea how to get back to default state? So that all my preferences would be lost as well as having activated only the plugins active by default?

**Some background**

My feeling is that it takes quite some time for the gedit to launch on my system and would like to start with the clean table once again.

**Distros/versions**

I'd like to achieve this on both of my systems: Xubuntu 12.10 (gedit 3.6) as well as Fedora 17 (gedit 3.4.2).

Answer (score 2):

In your home find the `gedit` folder and delete its content (or the folder itself), which holds your preferences and settings. In Fedora it should be under:

```
/home/username/.gnome2/gedit
/home/username/.gconf/apps/gedit-2
/home/username/.gconf/apps/gnome-settings/gedit
```

Comment: thank you, but it didn't work for me. I moved the folder away, afterwards restarted gedit, but still the theme is non-standard one as well as plugins used are the ones I had the last time

Comment: I made a change to the answer to reflect more locations where it could be found.

Comment: thanks, but stoll no luck with that. I don't have such dirs (the alter two) present on my fedora at all. However I use gedit 3 instead on gedit 2. that might be the reason.

Comment: run this and see what are the locations: `find / -name 'gedit*'`