# Gedit not saving settings - Fedora 21

Tags: gedit

I have Fedora 21 and gedit won't save config settings (like tab width, auto-indent, etc.). I tried deleting the configuration files directory per this question: [gedit reverting settings to default](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84604/gedit-reverting-settings-to-default), but nothing really came of it. Is there another way besides simply not using gedit?